# Preventing TOCTTOU (Time of check to time of use)

Tags: php, security, pdo

I have been learning about making an authentication system more secure.  One of the problems with my code is that it is vulnerable to a Time of check to time of use bug.  Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT username, password, email FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
    $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($rows != null) {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "name already exists";
        } else {
            $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(company, username, password, first_name, last_name, address, address2, city, state, zip, phone, email) VALUES (:company, :username, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :email)");
        $result = $stmt->execute(array(':company' => $company, ':username' => $username, ':password' => $hashed_password, ':first_name' => $firstName, ':last_name' => $lastName, ':address' => $address1, ':address2' => $address2, ':city' => $city, ':state' => $states, ':zip' => $zip, ':phone' => $phone, ':email' => $email));
        if ($result) {
            // Success
            $_SESSION["message"] = "You've successfully registered.";
            redirect_to("login.php");
        } else {
            // Failure
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Registration failed.";
        }
    }
}
} else {
// This is probably a GET request
}
```

So, it is first seeing if the user exists and if not, then to go ahead and insert the user's information into the database.   But this creates a vulnerability for TOCTTOU.  To fix this, I made the 'username' column UNIQUE.  Is this the only thing I need to do?   Is there a way to combine these two statements so it isn't vulnerable to that type of attack?

I've been reading resources on this and it seems making the column UNIQUE or PRIMARY is the best option.  But, I don't want to rely on the database.  Any suggestions?   Thanks!

Here is my fixed code:

At top of file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then:

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection->beginTransaction();
try {
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);
$check = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if ($check) {
    $_SESSION["message"] = "name already exists";
} else {
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users(company, username, password, first_name, last_name, address, address2, city, state, zip, phone, email) VALUES (:company, :username, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :email)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':company' => $company, ':username' => $username, ':password' => $hashed_password, ':first_name' => $firstName, ':last_name' => $lastName, ':address' => $address1, ':address2' => $address2, ':city' => $city, ':state' => $states, ':zip' => $zip, ':phone' => $phone, ':email' => $email)); // this should throw an exception if it fails, no need to check the return value
    $_SESSION["message"] = "You've successfully registered.";
}
$connection->commit();
redirect_to("login.php");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
$connection->rollBack();
throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Transactions, use them

Comment: I don't understand how that fixes it.  Can't two of the same transactions be done at the same time?

Comment: No, they can't. See http://php.net/manual/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: That page is really interesting.  So, it doesn't say; can I use the if statement in the transaction before committing or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the transaction. Your transaction would contain the check and insert with a commit (or rollback) to end the transaction

Comment: So, I can do really complex stuff using transactions?  I think you've opened a whole new world for me.  Thanks!  Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would maintain the unique constraint on your table as that makes sense from a data perspective.

For your PHP code, simply use transactions. For example...

```
// make sure you have $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
$connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);
    $check = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if ($check) {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "name already exists";
    } else {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO  ...');
        $stmt->execute([...]); // this should throw an exception if it fails, no need to check the return value
        $_SESSION["message"] = "You've successfully registered.";
    }
    $connection->commit();
    redirect_to("login.php");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $connection->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: That isn't terribly complicated.  So, on the $stmt->execute([...]); part, do I put array(':company' => $company, etc. inside the brackets?
Also, so what this does is it is storing instructions of what it will do and when it gets to commit - it does those instructions?  And this way, everything is done in one move instead of two?

Comment: Yes, I just abbreviated your code (didn't feel like banging out the entire `INSERT` statement and all the params). You should probably read up on how databases work with transactions but essentially yes, it's like building a queue of instructions that are guaranteed ACID.

Comment: ok, I'll read up on it.   When I upload the page, it is blank.  Do I need to check if my server can handle transactions or something?  Should I put my fixed code into my question?

Comment: @SherwoodPro Have you set the PDO error mode as indicated in my answer? Pop `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your script while developing (even better to set them in your dev environment `php.ini` file)

Comment: Yeah I did, and when I put that at the top of the page, it is still blank.  I've pasted my code above.  What you did makes sense to me I think, I'm not missing any brackets or anything.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If it's less than 5.4, my array shorthand syntax will have to be replaced with `array(...)`

Comment: It is 5.3.3.  I turned on error reporting.  It says that there is an unexpected [ when it expects ).  That is on the second $stmt.  I think I need to upgrade somehow.  it is a dedicated server from a hosting company.